# check twitter login id is already in database

Tags: php, twitter-oauth

I'm using twitter login for my site,when user entered with his twitter login id then how can I check this user is already registered in my database or new user.

and 1 more thing-
when I print print_r($user_info); then I received

```
stdClass Object
 (
[id_str] => 395809931
[default_profile] => 1
[time_zone] => 
[created_at] => Sat Oct 22 08:45:33 +0000 2011
[profile_text_color] => 333333
[protected] => 
[default_profile_image] => 1
[profile_background_image_url] => http://a0.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png
[name] => om nath
```

and more........
)
 how can I read and use this [id_str] .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for starters, you can pull out the `id_str` by accessing the `id_str` property of the `$user_info` object.

```
$id = $user_info->id_str;
```

After that, figuring out if they are already registered is dependent on how you are storing your users.  Is twitter oauth the only mechanism for logging in?  If so, then you can use the id_str as your primary key for your user table.  Then you would just do a query against the DB to see if they exist.  Assuming mysql, your query would be something like

```
SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_id = '$id';
```